# Unable to save uuid in elasticsearch

Tags: go, elasticsearch

i need to save some data where it consist of a fields called ID which is an **uuid** im using golang and **olivere** elastic search package here is my code

```
type Space struct {
    ID      string   `json:"id"`
    Name    string   `json:"name"`
    Type    string   `json:"type"`
}
```

After doing some conversions

```
    js := string(data)
    // upto this place there is no error or warnings
    ind, err := esclient.Index().
        Index(Type).
        BodyJson(js).
        Do(ctx)
```

Here is the error it throws

> failed to parse field [id] of type [long] in document with id
> 'gPmI8HIBCIO6Ejb-Y51D'. Preview of field's value:
> 'a5c723c5-1f6e-457f-9556-47b7ebcfd183'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Error message is very clear that you are trying to store `a5c723c5-1f6e-457f-9556-47b7ebcfd183` which is a string and not long as `id` field is mapped as `long` in your elasticsearch mapping.

It's even also telling that you got an error for document with `_id` having `gPmI8HIBCIO6Ejb-Y51D` as value, so you can find this document and correct it.

Please send the proper value of the below field, valid `long` in your case in order to solve the issue.

```
ID      string   `json:"id"`
```

Refer [this](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/master/server/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/index/mapper/FieldMapper.java#L251) code from Elasticsearch which parse the values and throws the exception, if you want to get more code level details.

Comment: thanks I did the changes you mentioned and now its working

Comment: @TRomesh great just woke up and gald to hear I could be of help :)